# ActiveSync sync mail with thread

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, microsoft-sync-framework, activesync

I am developing MS Exchange client using active sync protocol and i have implemented all the commands, able to fetch, read mails, can also mark as unread or can delete it. But now i want to manage the emails thread wise, so i am wondering if there is any way to manage email thread. I tried to find the thread index property but there isn't such a property like gmail or other imap protocol have. So i am wondering how can i implement it.

I have referred document from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd299441(v=exchg.80).aspx but didn't get exact solution from there.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using protocol version 14.0 or higher (meaning that the server is Exchange 2010 or higher), each message should have a [ConversationId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee159339(v=exchg.80).aspx) element and a [ConversationIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee203955(v=exchg.80).aspx) that you can use to group messages. There's more information in the ActiveSync Conversations Protocol document, [[MS-ASCON]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633488(v=exchg.80).aspx).